# How to create “RegistryAuth” for Private Registry Login Credentials

Tags: go, docker, docker-registry

I created a Private Registry using following command:

```sh
docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry -e REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED=true registry:2
```

I am trying to push Images to this registry using Golang docker client API -> `ImagePush`

```golang
func (cli *Client) ImagePush(ctx context.Context, image string, options types.ImagePushOptions) (io.ReadCloser, error)
```

When I zoom into `ImagePushOptions` I see that struct is

```golang
type ImagePullOptions struct {
    # All bool
    RegistryAuth string // RegistryAuth is the base64 encoded credentials for the registry
    PrivilegeFunc RequestPrivilegeFunc
}
```

AnyIdea how to create RegistryAuth String

I tried doing following:

```golang
type AuthArgs struct {
    Username string json:"username"
    Password string json:"password"
    Email string json:"email"
    ServerAddress string json:"serveraddress"
}

func() {
    m := AuthArgs{"docker", "docker", "", "localhost:5000"}
    b, err := json.Marshal(m)

    fmt.Println(string(b))
    encodeStr := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(b)

    refStr := "localhost:5000/" + image + ":" + tag
    fmt.Println(refStr)
    resp, err := cli.ImagePush(ctx, refStr, types.ImagePushOptions{RegistryAuth: encodeStr })
```

I am stuck from 3 days, any help would be great

Answer (score 7):

```
auth := types.AuthConfig{
    Username: cfg.User,
    Password: cfg.Passwd,
}
authBytes, _ := json.Marshal(auth)
authBase64 := base64.URLEncoding.EncodeToString(authBytes)
```

https://github.com/leopoldxx/godocker/blob/master/docker.go

Comment: I am able to push the image, but it is not pushing manifests and layers. Do I need to modify anything to push everything ?

Comment: @ChiragTayal did you ever get a full push to work. Having trouble getting manifests and layers pushed too.